# How to convert Map<String, Set<String>> to Map<String, String[]> in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap, set

I am getting data in the form of `Map<String, Set<String>>` from a method. But I want it to be in the form of `Map<String, String[]>`.

I.e, i want to convert only map values from `Set<String>` to `String[]` array for a particular key.

I tried this way , iterating the loaded set map and getting the String[] array of values correctly for a key.

But I just want to know that, is there any better  solution than this.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> testmap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        Map<String, String[]> testmapArray = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        Set<String> testSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        testSet.add("1");
        testSet.add("2");
        testSet.add("3");

        testmap.put("A", testSet);
        testmapArray.put("A", testSet.toArray(new String[testSet.size()]));

        Set<String> testSet1 = new TreeSet<String>();
        testSet1.add("4");
        testSet1.add("5");
        testSet1.add("6");

        testmap.put("B", testSet1);
        testmapArray.put("A", testSet1.toArray(new String[testSet1.size()]));

        System.out.println(testmap);

        Iterator it = testmap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            testmapArray.put(pair.getKey().toString(), testmap.get(pair.getKey()).toArray(new String[testmap.get(pair.getKey()).size()]));
        }
        System.out.println(testmapArray);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What you are doing is descent enough. Goahed.

Comment: Well, you still should avoid raw-types ;).

Comment: @Tom  yes.. that is the reason i posted this as, I am getting some warnings out of this code..!!!

Comment: So? Since you already know what generic types are (you already using them), you should be able to not use a raw `Iterator`. So add the generic types. You can do that :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is nearly working, so you should just consider couple of things:

1. `Iterator` is generic type, so you shouldn't do additional casting
2. There's no point in using `Iterator` explicitly: `for` loop is doing that implicitly for every `Iterable` (which `Collection -> Set` is)
3. You're using only `key` in `Map.Entry`, but you can use value too, there's no need to call `get` two additional times

So, the conversion would be:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry: testmap.entrySet()) {
    testmapArray.put(entry.getKey(),
            entry.getValue().toArray(new String[entry.getValue().size()]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Java 8 then you can achieve it using streams:

```
testmapArray = testmap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry ->  entry.getKey(), entry-> setToArray(entry.getValue())));
```

The method `setToArray` is:

```
private static String[] setToArray(Set<String> set) {
        return set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
    }
```